# Unable to read or write file to a local directory through Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, filereader

I am trying to read a file from local directory D:\, but Java throws a file not found exception. The file is present. If I load the same file from the src folder it works fine. I want to load it from a external location only. I am using jdk 1.8 and eclipse oxygen. The same thing works fine when deployed in tom cat and run. The problem is present only when trying to run from eclipse

```
String propFileName = "D://Properties.properties";
try {
  inputEIDVariables = new FileInputStream(propFileName);
  if (inputEIDVariables == null)
    System.out.println("Unable to find File" + propFileName);
  else if (inputEIDVariables != null) {
    properties.load(inputEIDVariables);
    System.out.println("Found the file" + " " + propFileName);
    System.out.println("Class" + " " + properties.getProperty("Class"));
  }
}
```

Comment: String propFileName = "D://Properties.properties";
 try
 {
     inputEIDVariables =new FileInputStream(propFileName);
  if (inputEIDVariables == null)
   System.out.println("Unable to find File" + propFileName);
  else if(inputEIDVariables != null)
  {
   properties.load(inputEIDVariables);
   System.out.println("Found the file" + " " + propFileName);
   System.out.println("Class" + " " + properties.getProperty("Class"));
  }

Comment: For sure `D://Properties.properties` looks strange, I guess it should be `D:/Properties.properties` or `D:\\Properties.properties` - second will be represented as `D:\Properties.properties` - backslash is escaping character for others.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file path. It should be absolute path if you are using windows it should be like i.e. 
D:/application.properties

Comment: Yes I have given the absolute path and yes I use windows

Comment: It seems that there is issue with permission . Try to put file in some other directory and then run.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
InputStream inputEIDVariables = null;
String propFileName = "D://Properties.properties";
try
{
    inputEIDVariables =new FileInputStream(propFileName);
    if (inputEIDVariables == null)
        System.out.println("Unable to find File" + propFileName);
    else if(inputEIDVariables != null)
    {
        properties.load(inputEIDVariables);
        System.out.println("Found the file" + " " + propFileName);
        System.out.println("Class" + " " + properties.getProperty("Class"));
    }
```

This is the code I have used to test the exception

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to add something edit your question instead and delete this "answer"!

Comment: Thank you!! I will make sure of that from next time

Comment: Why not this time? Edit your question and delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the double slashes, once I changed to single slash it worked. But with double slash it works when deployed as war file in server (another code, not the one above). The problem is only when run from eclipse. Thanks for the help.